# querySelector doesn't find part of the document

Tags: javascript, html, css, electron

I'm trying to make a simple close button for my electron application.
But for some reason document.querySelector('*') doesn't work for the top bar of my application..
And even if I manage to select specifically the div that is in charge of the close button, the click event listen doesn't fire..

here is my main.js:

```
const path = require('path')
require('electron-reload')(__dirname);

const createWindow = () =>{
    const win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 400, // width = 400
        height: 600, // height = 600
        frame: false,
        opacity: 0.98,
        webPreferences: {
            preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
        }
    })
    //win.webContents.openDevTools();
    win.setResizable(false);
    win.loadFile('index.html')
    // add button check
    ipcMain.on('exit-app', () => {
        console.log('clicked on something')
    })
}

app.whenReady().then(() => {
    createWindow()
})

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
    if(process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})
```

here is my index.html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css">
<html>
    <div class="titlebar">
        <div class="buttons">
            <p id="text">Omer's Electron Application</p>
            <div id="close"> </div>
            <div id="minimize"> </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <head>
        <title>
            Omer's Electron Application
        </title>
    </head>
    <script src="./index.js"></script>
</html>
```

here is my preload.js:

```
const {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{

    document.querySelector('*').addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        ipcRenderer.send('exit-app')
    })

})
```

here is my styles.css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto+Serif');

* {
    background-color: #525252;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-family: 'Roboto Serif', serif;
}
.titlebar *{
    background-color: #414141;
    height: 40px;
    -webkit-app-region: drag;
    position: fixed;
}
#text{
    position: fixed;
    left: 50px;
    top: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    color: #e0e0e0;
}
.buttons > div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    text-align: center;
    position: fixed;
    left: 370px;
    top: 7px;
}
.buttons > #close{
    background-color: #eb5a55;
}
.buttons > #minimize{
    background-color: #f4bb40;
    position: fixed;
    left: 340px;
}
```

Comment: button has to be in the dom in order to attach an event to it.

Comment: actually i see the problem. use `querySelectorAll('*')` for multiple elements.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. An `<html>` tag must have exactly one `<head>` and one `<body>` and nothing else. The rest must be inside one of those two. `<link>` outside of the `<html>` tag is also invalid.

Comment: @chovy I wanted to select a single element (the quit button that I made), but just for debugging I wrote document.querySelector('*') to check if the even is even being fired which is not.

Comment: @Ivar Thanks, I'm new to the whole html css js world :)
After changing still doesn't work..

Comment: why not do `const button = document.queySelector('button');` and then attach the event?

Comment: @chovy I don't think it would change anything, and for a single line I wouldn't assign it to a variable..
Seems pointless to me 

Comment: It's like the whole top bar is not a part of the html document or something and I can't figure out why

Comment: create a fiddle and we'll take a look

Comment: @chovy Can I send you a link to the github ?

Comment: fiddle only please

Comment: @chovy I don't know how to use it

Comment: then learn. you paste the html in the html box...the css in the css and the js in the js box....what's there to understand?

Comment: @chovy the fiddler doesn't include the backend ?

Answer (score 0):

I bumped into this thread randomly and found the answer I was looking for !
[Change Cursor on Draggable region in Electron](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47063878/change-cursor-on-draggable-region-in-electron)

> Unfortunately setting -webkit-app-region: drag; disables all click and mouse events because it's treated as a title-bar so you can't change the cursor.
> I would include where I read that but I can't find it anymore.
> See:
> #1354 -webkit-app-region: drag eats all click events
> #8730 Frameless Electron App not work css cursor:pointer

So apparently after removing -webkit-app-region: drag the issue was fixed and all mouse events worked like magic !